# How to change Header Parameters while using angular-file-upload for uploading multiple files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-file-upload

I have this requirement to add file name in header while uploading each file. I am using a single uploader for selecting multiple files.
I tried doing this

```
 $scope.uploader.onAfterAddingFile = function (fileItem) {
       $scope.uploader.headers.fileName = fileItem.name;
 };
```

But its not changing. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with this:

```
$scope.uploader.queue[$scope.uploader.queue.length - 1].file.name = "prefix-" + fileItem.file.name;
```

Comment: i want to add the new parameter in header itself

Comment: Try to set in headers for that object param like: `uploader.queue[uploader.queue.length - 1].headers.newParam = fileItem.file.name;`

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
$scope.uploader.onBeforeUploadItem = function (fileItem) {    
  fileItem.headers = {
    fileName: fileItem.name
  };
}
```